# is there any way to initialize a varirable with another variable that's declared above it?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm a beginner on Flutter is there any way to initialize a varirable with another variable that's declared above it ?

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can by initializing the second variable in the `initState()` Function in `statefulWidget` class .

Answer (score 2):

You can do lazy initialization by adding `late` on second variable declaration like

```
Foo foo = Foo();
late int data= foo.value;
```

Comment: More about [lazy-initialization](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#lazy-initialization)

Comment: `late` is not necessary in this example.

Comment: yea, you are right,  BT adding late will work  the thing OP trying to do[assumption while snippet is missing]